# Unable to create Mysql service in GKE. Throwing error "services "mysql" is forbidden: Use of external IPs is denied by admission control"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-kubernetes-engine

I am creating a service in GKE and getting the following error.

> Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "mysqlse.yml": services "mysql" is forbidden: Use of external IPs is denied by admission control

Following is my code.

```js
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: mysql
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: mysql-dev
    chart: mysql-2.0.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: mysql-dev
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"mysql","argocd.argoproj.io/instance":"mysql-dev","chart":"mysql-2.0.0","heritage":"Helm","release":"mysql-dev"},"name":"mysql","namespace":"dev"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"mysql","port":3306,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":3306}],"selector":{"app":"mysql","release":"mysql-dev"},"type":"ClusterIP"}}
spec:
  ports:
    - name: mysql
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
    release: mysql-dev
  clusterIP: x.x.x.148
  clusterIPs:
    - x.x.x.148
  type: ClusterIP
  externalIPs:
    - x.x.x.x
  sessionAffinity: None
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the DenyServiceExternalIPs admission controller enabled. It's  enabled by default on GKE cluster > 1.21

you can check it out by running

> gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER_NAME

and to disabled it run

> gcloud beta container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME 
> --enable-service-externalips